# how to describe the owner of something embedded inside them?

Tags: word-choice

I have the following sentence in my story

> Almost everyone has implanted under their skin a sensor that monitors
>   their vitals and health in real-time and could alert the wearer of
>   potentially hazardous health events. It can detect whether the wearer
>   is unconscious and automatically call medical services.

I'm wondering if "wearer" is the appropriate word to describe the owner of the embedded sensor or if there is a better word since the sensor is technically inside them? I don't think "owner" describes it appropriately.

Comment: Depends a lot on the speaker and his/her attitude towards this feature.  I do agree, wearer is not correct, though it might be "focus grouped" by the manufacturer to assuage the fears of "Big Brother" knows when you're having a heart attack.

Comment: "Subject"? "Host"?

Comment: Just use the word "person." It's more natural and it will be clear who you mean by the context.

Comment: Requests to rephrase your work are not on topic.  [This explains what is on topic for writing SE](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thanks, @Alexander! I can mark yours as the answer.

Comment: Welcome Kamal! Although this is not on topic here, it would be on topic on English SE. I have voted to have it automatically migrated there.

Comment: How about "bot"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

- "Subject" (as in "test subject" or "surveillance subject")
- "Host" (as in "host organism")

Answer (score 0):

I feel like "wearer" is OK, because it's under their skin. Tattoos are also "in" your body, but everyone says "on".

If "wearer" seems inappropriate, I'd say "user" or "owner".

Answer (score 0):

I believe ***host*** is the word you need. The OED confirms its use in the following two contexts:

> 3a. Biology. An animal or plant having a parasite or commensal
> habitually living in or upon it.
>
> 3b. Biology and Medicine. An animal
> or person that is the recipient of tissue, an organ, etc., that has
> been transplanted into it from another.

It seems a small step to include as a third category, an animal or person who has a mechanical or electronic implant, for whatever purpose.